# In long run, Which is the best way to connect a flex duct to a Take Off Start Collar?

Tags: hvac, ducts

Please, Please vote up to a right answer.

I found in the internet, Connecting a flex duct  to take off start collar/ connect still a debatable,
I need an answer from people of this community. Thanks!

Edited : I found few of these options available. I am not sure if there could be more way.

1. Attach flex to take off, then zip ties to secure and finally foil tape
2. Attach flex to take off, then use Gear clamp to secure and finally foil tape
3. Attach flex to take off, then mastic sealant from inside of flex duct and then zip ties or clamp finally foil tape if needed

Flex :

[image]

Take off start collar :

[image]

Comment: It might help if you listed the options you have come across along with the pros/cons. Of course, if there are many acceptable options (as you seem to indicate) then this becomes a "what's best" question and those usually come down to opinion (of which you've found many).

Comment: Added options. If I had known pros/cons of each then I can decide myself which suites better my need :)

Comment: Are you talking about the standard practice to zip tie and tape to the collar?  For example I zip tie the inner duct and tape then zip tie the outer duct. I use quality 3m zip ties as I have found cheap ones break or just don’t hold as well.  Some only use tape on the inner duct and ties outside.

Comment: Yes. How about mastic sealant from inside duct first then zip tie  ?

Comment: You can get 7 different answers by asking 3 different people. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m1eRBXDM5I&t=655s) they apply mastic to the outside of the flex duct just to appease the inspector, not because it makes sense, **but to appease the inspector**. Let that sink in for a second and now consider how much crap you read on forums are for appeasing an inspector.

Comment: I would apply mastic, zip-tie the duct to it or gear-clamp it, and wrap the outside end with tape to avoid fraying of the insulation. Make sure to let the mastic cure before sending cold air through it or else it will never dry.